# Swift - UIButton overriding setSelected

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass

I'm making a UIButton subclass in Swift to perform custom drawing and animation on selection

What would be the equivalent in Swift of overriding `- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected` in ObjC?

I tried

`override var selected: Bool`

so I could implement an observer but I get

`Cannot override with a stored property 'selected'`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Like others mentioned you can use `willSet` to detect changes.  In an override, however, you do not need assign the value to super, you are just observing the existing change.

A couple things you can observe from the following playground:

1. Overriding a property for `willSet/didSet` still calls super for `get/set`.  You can tell because the state changes from `.normal` to `.selected`.
2. willSet and didSet are called even when the value is not changing, so you will probably want do the compare the value of `selected` to either `newValue` in `willSet` or `oldValue` in `didSet` to determine whether or not to animate.

```
import UIKit

class MyButton : UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet {
            print("changing from \(isSelected) to \(newValue)")
        }

        didSet {
            print("changed from \(oldValue) to \(isSelected)")
        }
    }
}

let button = MyButton()

button.state == .normal
button.isSelected = true // Both events fire on change.
button.state == .selected
button.isSelected = true // Both events still fire.
```

Comment: In **SWIFT3** `selected` has been renamed to `isSelected` ... Please update :)

Comment: @Husam Updated. :)

Answer (score 7):

you'd do it like e.g. this:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {

    // ...

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        willSet(newValue) {
            super.isSelected = newValue;
            // do your own business here...
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Ok this works even without the public/internal keyword as suggested by diegomen. I was getting the error because I hadn't yet included the {} with the observer, silly me... But I still don't understand why they are compulsory...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override public var selected: Bool {
    willSet(selectedValue) {
        self.selected = selectedValue
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Xcode gives me a warning and suggests to replace public with internal. Could you please explain why the internal keyword is necessary? Thanks.

Comment: Using internal you're saying that you can access to the var from the same module. You got more info here: http://www.codingricky.com/access-control-in-swift/ Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Create IBAction and check button selected or not in swift language.

```
@IBAction func favoriteButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    // Save Data
    sender.selected  = !sender.selected;

    if (sender.selected)
    {
        NSLog(" Not Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(" Selected");
    }

}
```