# selected and deselected checkbox in Swift

Tags: swift, checkbox

How to know my button selected or not in swift 3 `.selected` property  not found.

when i type `checkBtn.selected` not found in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.0)

```
 if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        if button.selected {
            // set selected
            button.selected = true
        } else {
            // set deselected
            button.selected = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: see tis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364869/swift-uibutton-overriding-setselected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this below code

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        if button.isSelected {
            // set selected
            button.isSelected = true
        } else {
            // set deselected
            button.isSelected = false
        }
    }
```

For shorthand, try this

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
     button.isSelected = !button.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Or simply `button.isSelected.toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

In swift 3 you will have **isSelected** instead of **selected**. Your code looks fine just make a change.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let button = sender as? UIButton {
    if button.isSelected {
        //for selected input            
    } else {
        //for not selected input 
    }
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected //toggle the text box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnCheckBox: UIButton!
@IBAction func btnCheckBoxClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if btnCheckBox.isSelected {
            btnCheckBox.isSelected = false
            btnCheckBox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_checkbox_inactive"), for: .normal)
        }else {
            btnCheckBox.isSelected = true
            btnCheckBox.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_checkbox_active"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

It worked for me.