# I want to use bool on button, if i click on button image of imageview changed and if again click on button then image reverse using Swift

Tags: swift, image, button, boolean

my code is:
func PickUpCarCost() {

```
        imgCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")
        imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")
        if CarPickUpButton?.tag == 1 {
            imgCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
           self.pickupChargelabel.text=self.PickUpFare.text!
        }
        else {
            imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")

        }

}
```

in this i wants take bool like if button selectes image view image will be check.png if unselect image view image will be uncheck.png how to code for this in swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can you isSelected variable. And add different image for button state.

```
imgCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck.png"), for: .selected)
imgCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "check.png"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on your button like this. or you can use **UIButton** own property isSelected ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myBtn: UIButton!
```

In your **Viewdidload** method add these line

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap")  

myBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  if sender.state == .ended {
      // handling code
  }
  else if sender.state == .began {

  }
}
```

Add gesture according to your needs.I used long tap and tap gesture

Comment: sorry, i cant do dis i wants to aply only bool on button. in whchi when uibuttonClick==true{ // imge changed of image view } else if uibuttoclick==fase image reverse

Comment: check the ans of this guy if you dont want to use tap gesture,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364869/swift-uibutton-overriding-setselected

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Globally define `var isclick = false`

```
 func CarDeliverCost() {
        if (!isclick){

            imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
            isclick=true



        }
        else
        {
            imgUnCheck.image = UIImage(named: "uncheck.png")
            isclick=false



        }
    }
```